# Difference between weak and Euclidean topology on CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Weak topology on CW complex $X$ is defined with a condition:

Subset $A \subseteq X$ is open in $X$ iff $A \cap e$ is open in $e$ for every cell $e$ in $X$.

As far as I understand, in case when CW complex is embedded in Euclidean space, the induced Euclidean topology and the weak topology do not necassary coincide on infinte CW complexes, but I can't imagine any simple example of such CW complex.

Can anyone give me an example and show why it is better to take the weak topology?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, specify what do you mean by the Euclidean topology on a CW complex.

Comment: If you *embed* a space $X$ in Euclidean space, then you have a homeomorphism between $X$ and its image $X'$. Perhaps you mean something like the metric topology on the geometric realization of abstract simplicial complexes. This differs from the standard "weak" topology.